# The document element is not available

Tags: jxbrowser

Sometimes I get error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The document element is not available.
when doing a findElements call on the Document. Is there a way to test if the document element is available rather than catching the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether document element exists or not using the following code:

```
DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
DOMElement documentElement = document.getDocumentElement();
if (documentElement != null) {
    DOMElement element = documentElement.findElement(By.className("name"));
}
```

In general, the following code is doing the same thing, but throws exception if documentElement is null:

```
DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
DOMElement element = document.findElement(By.className("name"));
```